# How to sort stacked bar chart on certain value of bar in charts.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have used a script I found here on stack overflow to sort a stacked bar chart. The only thing is that the stacked bars get sorted by the sum of the total bar. I've been struggling with the script below, but can't find a way to sort the stacked bars based on one value of the stack instead of the sum of the stacked bars. This is the code I'm using:

```
Chart.plugins.register({    
    id:"p2",                                                                                                                                                         
    datasets: [],                                                                                                                                                                    
    getData(labels, datasets) {                                                                                                                                                      
        const sum = [];                                                                                                                                                            
        for (i = 0; i < datasets[0].length; i++) {                                                                                                                                   
            sum.push({                                                                                                                                                               
                label: labels[i],                                                                                                                                                    
                data: datasets.map(e => e[i]),                                                                                                                                       
                    get sum() { // ES6 - getter                                                                                                                                      
                        return this.data.reduce((a, b) => a + b);                                                                                                                    
                    }                                                                                                                                                                
            });                                                                                                                                                                      
        }                                                                                                                                                                            
        return sum;                                                                                                                                                                  
    },                                                                                                                                                                               
    beforeUpdate(chart) {                                                                                                                                                              
        chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset, datasetIndex) => {                                                                                                                     
            this.datasets.push(dataset.data);                                                                                                                                        
        });                                                                                                                                                                          
        const data_store = this.getData(chart.data.labels, this.datasets).sort((a,b) => b.sum - a.sum);                                                                              

        data_store.forEach((d,i) => {                                                                                                                                                
            chart.data.labels[i] = d.label;                                                                                                                                          
            d.data.forEach((v, vi) => {                                                                                                                                              
                chart.data.datasets[vi].data[i] = v;                                                                                                                                 
            });                                                                                                                                                                      
        });                                                                                                                                                                          
    }                                                                                                                                                                                
});
```

Comment: could you add a fiddle? some data to fiddle with would be nice

Comment: Does this maybe answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51671842/2358409

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sort function is currently using the sum:

```
.sort((a,b) => b.sum - a.sum)
```

So replace that with the data you want sorted:

```
.sort((a,b) => b.data[i] - a.data[i])
```

Where `i` is the row you desire.

Comment: That did it. Thx for your help!

Comment: One more question. When I try to sort the stacked bar now it works, but when I try to sort it again I get: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined". Any ideas on that? Thx in advance.